# tracking progress of remote call that pulls serialized object

Tags: java, spring, serialization, client-server, httpinvoker

I have a client/server application that uses Java/Spring.  The client accesses the server via httpinvokers and makes requests that return serialized objects.

We have a call that pulls over a very large 50mb + serialized object.  Obviously, this call takes several minutes to process.  Is there a way to track the progress of this call?  For instance, it would be perfect if I could test the amount of data transferred while the call is in progress, maybe by using a separate thread.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

you would have to make 2 different calls (2nd would be asynchronous). Your server would implement an observer pattern to update data which is transferred to the object which is observing it. The server would be writing this 50MB data in chunks rather than in stream.

The observer class would be the other class which you will call asynchronously. The observer would keep returnign how much data has been trasnfered.

Its kind a same concept that Gmail implemented before HTML5 was released in Attachment upload progress bar. What they did is that with html control they uploaded the attachment which was being written in server side and at the same time, they used flash objects to send call to that server to see how much data has been saved.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I was hoping to do something while maintaining the single call model.  Is there no way to do this?